# Updating PyQt5 GUI with Live Data

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I created a PyQt5 GUI using QtDesigner and converted it to Python. I was planning to update and display the value from the sensor reading from the Raspberry Pi. Since the GUI is in a loop, there is no way I can update data from outside that loop. Currently I used the code below where I use the QTimer widget that executes the function every given interval. Is this solution appropriate or not? What other methods are available to accomplish this task?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from uimainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    numTest=0;

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.getSensorValue)

    def getSensorValue(self):
        print(self.numTest)
        self.numTest=self.numTest+1
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.getSensorValue)

    if __name__=="__main__":
        import sys
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        w=MainWindow()
        w.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `QTimer` would be my first choice. May be, `QThread` could be an alternative but I see no reason why to add multi-threading issues in your  case. Why do you use `QTimer.singleShot()`? Are you aware that you can setup a `QTimer` object which "fires" periodically (considering the interval set by `QTimer.setInverval()`)?

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use a `QTimer` which calls a member function periodically:

1. Make a member variable of `QTimer`.
2. Set interval of `QTimer` to the intended delay.
3. Connect `getSensorValue()` as signal handler to `QTimer.timeout()`.
4. Start `QTimer` member.

Demo `test-QTimer.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
  # constructor
  def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    # counter
    self.i = 0
    # add QLabel
    self.qLbl = QLabel('Not yet initialized')
    self.setCentralWidget(self.qLbl)
    # make QTimer
    self.qTimer = QTimer()
    # set interval to 1 s
    self.qTimer.setInterval(1000) # 1000 ms = 1 s
    # connect timeout signal to signal handler
    self.qTimer.timeout.connect(self.getSensorValue)
    # start timer
    self.qTimer.start()

  def getSensorValue(self):
    self.i += 1
    # print('%d. call of getSensorValue()' % self.i)
    self.qLbl.setText('%d. call of getSensorValue()' % self.i)

qApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
# setup GUI
qWin = MainWindow()
qWin.show()
# run application
sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

Tested in [**cygwin**](http://www.cygwin.org) on Windows 10:

[image: Snapshot of test-QTimer.py]